# How to know proxy used by http client in given request

Tags: http, go, tcp, proxy

I'm doing some requests through some proxy servers. The function that defines which proxy url to use will choose randomly from a list of proxies. I would like to know for a given request, which proxy url is being used. As far as I know, when using a proxy server the http headers remain the same, but the tcp headers are the one that change.

Here's some code illustrating it (no error handling for simplicity):

```
func main() {
    transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: chooseProxy}
    client := http.Client{Transport: transport}

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "https://www.google.com", nil)
    checkErr(err)

    // How to know here which proxy was used? Suppose the same client will perform several requests to different URL's.
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    checkErr(err)

    dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(response.Request, false)
    fmt.Println(dump)
}

func chooseProxy(request *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    proxies := []string{"proxy1", "proxy2", "proxy3"}

    proxyToUse := proxies[rand.Intn(len(proxies))]

    return url.Parse(proxyToUse)
}
```

I'm assuming that the Proxy function in the transport is called for each request even if the same client is used, as per the docs that say "Proxy specifies a function to return a proxy for a given Request". Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Some HTTP proxies add a `Via` header that tell who they are.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Via

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your chooseProxy function so that it saves the proxy selected.
To do that, you can transform the chooseProxy func into a method of a type that will be used as storage for the information you want to keep:

```
type proxySelector string

func (sel *proxySelector) chooseProxy(request *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    proxies := []string{"proxy1", "proxy2", "proxy3"}

    proxyToUse := proxies[rand.Intn(len(proxies))]

    *sel = proxySelector(proxyToUse) // <-----

    return url.Parse(proxyToUse)
}


func main() {
    var proxy proxySelector
    transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: proxy.chooseProxy}  // <-----
    client := http.Client{Transport: transport}

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "https://www.google.com", nil)
    checkErr(err)

    // How to know here which proxy was used? Suppose the same client will perform several requests to different URL's.
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    checkErr(err)

    dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(response.Request, false)
    fmt.Println(dump)
    fmt.Println("Proxy:", string(proxy))  // <-----
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request which contains the target URI is given as argument `request` to `chooseProxy`. So you can have the correct mapping already inside your `chooseProxy` function, all you need to to is check `proxyToUse` vs. `request.URL` there.

If you don't really trust the code that this mapping is actually done, then you need to look outside the code. For example you can look at the actual network traffic with Wireshark to see which proxy gets accessed.

Comment: I thought about that, but what i want to do is compare the proxy used vs the actual response. In that way I would have to make a mapping(say with logs) between the previous request(say a log in the chooseProxy function) and the response.